# Is it pythonic/safe to modify an array from within a lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas series containing (5 digit) zip codes. Some (few) of the elements in the series are actually strings with multiple zip codes separated by a '/'. I am looking to extract those special cases to an array, to later add them to the series. This following lambda function works:

```
other_zips = []
f = lambda s: other_zips.extend(s.split('/')) if '/' in s else s
zipcodes.apply(f)
```

I then have a list of 5 digit zip codes which I can add back to the original series. However, the solution appears a bit "bloated" to me - especially the `else s` part doesn't make sense semantically, but had to be included for syntactic reasons.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? In broader terms, is it a good idea to manipulate external values from within a lambda function in python?

Comment: What does it matter if it's from a `lambda`, regular function or just main code? As long as you are aware that you're modifying a mutable object and know what you're doing, choose whatever feels better for you... Anyway, it seems like this could be achieved with a simple list-comprehension. There is just no reason to use a lambda here, but it's perfectly fine...

Comment: Why did you write a lambda? Why not just a regular function? (Anything you can do with a lambda, you can do with a regular function.)

Comment: I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you because Pandas has its own idioms for manipulating series/dfs.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: in general, functions that mutate global objects are "code smell" in any language. There are entire schools of thought that say "all mutable state is bad", entire *paradigms* of programming where mutating state isn't possible, for what it is worth...

Comment: Addtionally, `f = lambda: ...` is explicitly against the style guidelines. The **only** reason to use a lambda expression is to create an anyonymous function. If you are going to assign your function object to a name, you might as well just use a full function definition statement.

Comment: I sometimes to this trying to split up a more complex statement to make it easier to understand. Thanks for the heads-up that it's against the style guidelines. In this particular case I went with a list comprehension similar to the one presented in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the most straight-forward and thus preferrable code would be something like the following.

```
other_zips = []
for zipcode in zipcodes:
    if "/" in zipcode:
        other_zips.extend(zipcode.split("/"))
```

If you're really into one-liners, the following list comprehension is pretty pythonic and I think easy to understand.

```
other_zips = [z for zipcode in zipcodes for z in zipcode.split("/") if "/" in zipcode]
```

I don't really like your code as I wouldn't expect `zipcodes.apply(f)` to change anything but `zipcodes`. This line just doesn't read like it's the one that actually builds the list `other_zips`.

Comment: I completely agree with your last point! The biggest issue with the original code is that you would expect `zipcodes.apply` to only change `zipcodes`, but it relys on side-effects which make it less clear

Comment: No, you wouldn't expect `zipcodes.apply(f)` **to change anything by itself**. That is strange.

Answer (score 0):

If that bothers you, you can do it this way using list comprehension.

```
import itertools
other_zips = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([
     zipcode.split('/') for zipcode in zipcodes
])
```

Checkout itertools. It has a lot of cool utils like this.

Comment: The `if/else` is not really necessary. You already get `[s]` from the `split` if there is no `/` there...

Comment: You're right. I will update the answer.

Comment: Now the code is just equivalent to `other_zips = s.split('/')`...

Comment: Wait, how does this work? `s` is not defined here.

Comment: I'm sorry. My brain was not working. I have updated it. Hope that helps.